# Laravel Model factories, one to many relationship without database access

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For my tests (Laravel 6) I am trying to use factories with `make()`, in order to **bypass the DB operations** just creating a new instance of the model.

Now, I am having an headache to make things work with my one to many relationship.

A skeleton of my code just to have an overview:

```php
class Fine extends Model {
    // Other things here

    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Model\Article');
    }
}
```

where `Article` does not have any other relationships.

Now, I would like to create a Fine factory to create an instance in which I can parse `$fine->articles`, all without any database interaction.

Here's the basic Fine factory that works (without using articles):

```
$factory->define(Fine::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        "id" => 10,
        Fine::FIELDONE => 'xxx',
        Fine::FIELDTWO => 'yyy',
    ];
});
```

that I use with  `$fine = factory(Fine::class)->make();` .

Now I need to "prefill" articles. I have tried with  `hydrate()` but it does not work.
I have tried with `afterMaking()` with different combinations of code:

```
$factory->afterMaking(Fine::class, function (Fine $fine, Faker $faker) {
    $articles = factory(\App\Model\Article::class, 3)->make([\App\Model\Article::FINE_ID => $fine->id]);
    // TEST WITH SAVEMANY: $fine->saveMany(factory(\App\Model\Article::class, 10)->make());
    // SAME WITH CREATEMANY
    // TEST WITH HYDRATE: $multa->articles()->hydrate([$article]);
    // $multa->load('articles');
});
```

Just to make a point I have tried different roads but, I admit, I am a bit lost.

Basically I end up with the classical

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found

error, so I am still accessing the database.

Now, I am starting to think that factories are a proper choice only if at the end one is going to store data on the database (I am sure that `saveMany()` is going to work if I use `create()` and not `make()`).

Can you please give me an hint on how to accomplish this task? If factories are not the right way to do it I am more than open to change my choice, too.

Thanks in advance!
Lorenzo

Comment: `saveMany()` will work only for `create()` like you said, because it tries to save them into the database. Can you give a little more info how you use this relation in your code and in your tests? Anywhere in your code where you do `$fine->articles()` is going to reach for the database, event if you prefill fake records into the relation. If you try to get the articles from the property like this `$fine->articles`, thats ok, but this is read-only and you can't set them this way.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment to clarify the saveMany() / create() stuff!
Basically I have a custom `toArray()` method in the Fine Model that performs a `foreach $this->articles`, so I am afraid I cannot "bypass the DB" in my tests, afterall (?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this information on a non existing model instance if you really have to:

```
$fine->setRelation(
    'articles', 
    factory(\App\Model\Article::class, 3)->make()
)
```

It depends what you plan on doing with this model and its relationship since there are no IDs set so they are not really related in that way.